# $\vec{v}(x)/|\vec{v}(x)|$ extends to the annulus bounded by the two spheres.

Tags: differential-topology

Guillemin and Pollack's Differential Topology Page 133:

$\vec{v}$ is a smooth map $\vec{v}: X \to \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\forall x, \vec{v}(x) \in T_x(X)$. Assume that we are in $\mathbb{R}^k$ and that $\vec{v}$ has an isolated zero at the origin. The directional variation of $\vec{v}$ around $0$ is measured by the map $x \to \vec{v}(x)/|\vec{v}(x)|$ carrying any small sphere $S_\epsilon$ around $0$ into $S^{k-1}$. Choosing the radius $\epsilon$ so small that $\vec{v}$ has no zeros inside $S_\epsilon$ except at the origin, we define the *index* of $\vec{v}$ at 0, $\operatorname{ind}_0(\vec{v})$, to be the degree of this directional map $S_\epsilon \to S^{k-1}$.

> As usual, the radius itself does not matter, for if $\epsilon^\prime$ is also suitable, then $\vec{v}(x)/|\vec{v}(x)|$ extends to the annulus bounded by the two spheres.

So I don't really get it here - why $\vec{v}(x)/|\vec{v}(x)|$ extends to the annulus bounded by the two spheres?

Comment: I'd call it "shell" instead of "annulus".

Comment: Oh I got it! So it actually means the sphere with greater radius, the sphere with smaller radius, and any sphere bounded between. Therefore it is called annulus, right @ChristianBlatter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not so much that $\frac{v(x)}{\vert v(x) \vert}$ *extends* into the annulus bounded by $S_\epsilon$ and $S_{\epsilon'}$ as is that it's already *defined* there by virtue of the fact that $v(x)$ has no zero within the larger, hence also the smaller, of these two spheres.

Comment: Thanks Robert. Yes I get what you said, but why annulus..?

Comment: @WishingFish:  not too sure I get the jist of your question, "why annulus?"  That's the name of such regions between two concentric spheres as I know it.

Comment: Sorry Robert, I wasn't clear. I thought it simply should be "$\vec{v}(x)/|\vec{v}(x)|$ extends to the sphere with greater radius..."

Comment: @WishingFish:  same difference though, no?  You can say it whichever way you like!

Comment: NO. I thought annulus is a ring without center circle. /_\ Or.. it actually means the sphere with greater radius, and the sphere with smaller radius, right? Now it all makes sense :D